# sheduler->powershell->.bat -> Win32 process never returns to script

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a powershell script which calls a batch file, which interacts with the user, then starts a Win32 app. The Win32 app opens a window and waits for a matching Win32 app to tell it to close. Between the opening and closing of the Win32 apps, control returns to the Batch file, which then returns control to the script.
**This all works properly when run from powershell.ise or explorer->run with powershell.** But when run from the scheduler, control never comes back after the Win32 runs aNd Windows Task Mgr thinks something is running. The script is set to run with my userid (which is an admin), it has compatibility set to run as admin and max privileges.
Any suggestions would be most welcome.

The following script runs as MY userid, User must be logged on.
This is the active function in the script:

```
Write-Host 'PowerShell script for Macrium Reflect Backup Definition File';
    Start-Process c:\BATS\m_scripts\bats_for_mscripts\Macrium-pre-C+E2M.bat 
  $iExitCode = Backup; # starts the Macrium program with the following line:
*$iResult = (Start-Process -FilePath $strReflectPath -ArgumentList $strArgs -PassThru -Wait).ExitCode;*
  Start-Process c:\BATS\m_scripts\bats_for_mscripts\Macrium-post-C+E2M.bat  
   Exit $iExitCode;
```

Here is the 1st BAT file (the second bat file calls the Win32 program that stops the 1st Win32 program):

```
echo This is Macrium-pre-C+E2M.bat
:again
if exist M:\ goto allok
@echo off
REM be sure there are no spaces after the equal signs in the next line
set inval=""
set /p inval="turn on the external drive for C: or E: backup and type an 'x'"
rem check for user data entry
if "%inval%". == "." goto again
if not "%inval%" == "x" goto again
:spinup
REM sleep a while (time in msecs)
echo WScript.Sleep 30000 > %temp%\sleep.vbs & cscript %temp%\sleep.vbs %sleepMs% //B & del %temp%\sleep.vbs

rem nudge the user again.
if not exist M:\ goto again
:allok
:exists
start "" "E:\DJs Documents\my_vs_executables\running_program-reminder.exe" macrium1
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that I needed to:

1. insert `$proc=`  in front of the `Start-Process` call and
2. replace `-Wait` with `-PassThru`
3. insert `$proc.WaitForExit()` after the `Start-Process` call.

Comment: That makes sense, but it also implies that, with `-Wait` in place, it cannot be true that your script worked as intended when run from the ISE / File Explorer.

Comment: I had tried so many scenarios, that it IS possible that I got the manual version to work without the -Wait. But none of my methods worked before changing to the one I marked as the answer.